# How to align to vertical center with empty TextView?

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have a problem with vertical align of two TextViews: when second TextView doesn't contain text it as before have some height.

So, I need this:

[image]

But see this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/menu"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="111111111111111"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/region"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to implement it?

Comment: I didn't get what do you want exactly? Could you please explain a bit more.

Comment: I need that the TextView ("region") doesn't take space when it empty. And TextView city will aligned by vertical center.

Comment: Try using `android:layout_weight="0.5"` for both the text Views. Extra space might be because for one `TextView` you are trying to have text which is of medium size( so will take extra height) andfor the second TextView the size is small. If both of them have same size then, the extra space might not be there.

Comment: Did you try making both `TextViews` of same size as well ?

Comment: You said that you want `TextView ("region") doesn't take space when it empty` but you didn't say what else are you doing? I mean you are aligning both your text view's to left of a button and then both of the TextView's are being vertically aligned to each other. But, now your problem is extra height in one of them as compared to another?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that thing programatically by giving second textview visibility to gone

```
          txtvw2.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

Comment: Okay, I remove it, but nothing changed.

Comment: what do you exactly want please explain in detail

Comment: I want that the TextView "city" will aligned by it own center, but not center of LinearLayout1. Please, look on the pictures. On second picture empty TextView take space.

Comment: `Takes Space`? You mean that your `region` textview should nto take any space if its empty?

Comment: you can do that thing programatically by giving second textview visibility to gone

Comment: @anddevmanu, I think about this, but I think that is not perfect method... Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically here is the java code:

```
TextView region = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.region);
String regionText = region.getText().toString();

if (!regionText.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    region.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    region.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@null"
  />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/menu"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff00">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="111111111111111"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/region"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```